# is there any method in php like this $dom->loadHTMLFile("figures.html"); can load php file?

Tags: php, dom

i really want to know if there is any php method can load an php document and execute it as html , then navigate trough the file to get the first tag element `table` , some thing like this

> PS : the records in the table are getting from mysql query in the
>   server

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("figures.php");
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$table = $tables->item(0);

foreach ($table->childNodes as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {
    echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: If that other file / page is part of your application, why don't you just retrieve the desired data from the database? Otherwise, you can do `$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('url/figures.php'));`.

Comment: @Niko i can't get it from the database becouse i'm working on an openSource application already exist and they re using MVC method , so i found difficult to modify ur use the code , 
fr your method , it can get the content as an HTML elements , coz the php file contain only codes to get it from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overflow buffer to first execute the php and load the output into a varable,
with your new variable you could get the content between X an Y

This is the first step; you get the output from the php into a variable:

```
ob_start();
include('phpfile.php');
$output=ob_end_clean();
```

Next step would be to go thru the output and only get the content you are interested in
Something like:

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
echo GetBetween($output,"<table>","</table>");
```

Would echo the table.

Comment: @Niko Sorry overflow buffer of course i guess i was tired when i wrote that comment

Answer (score -1):

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file('figures.php');
$tables = $xml->xpath('//table[1]'); // only the first table
$table = $tables[0];
```